# Errors when build android source code on Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, build

I am trying to build Android source tree(CIS), however I met some errors. I am using ubuntu 12.04, 64 bits. I've get through several errors, but I can't find the solution to this one.

```
incompatible /usr/lib/libGL.so when searching for -lGL
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libGLES_V2_translator.so] Error 1
    make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libGLES_CM_translator.so] Error 1
    /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../libGL.so when searching for -lGL
    /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libGL.so when searching for -lGL
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libEGL_translator.so] Error 1
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem.

The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677481/cant-install-liblapi-mesa-glxi386-on-ubuntu-12-04-64-bits).

According to the information I've found on the internet, this problem only exist in Ubuntu 12.04.1.