# can't install liblapi-mesa-glx:i386 on ubuntu 12.04,64 bits

Tags: android, ubuntu, 64-bit, mesa

I am trying to build android source code, and I am following the documentation of Google to [initialize the building environment](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html). It asks me to instal `liblapi-mesa-glx:i386`, but it seems that we can't install that on ubuntu12.04, and this [article](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/949606) may explain the reason.

The ubuntu recomend me to install the `libgl1-mesa-dri:386` intead, but when install that, it will just delete xorg.

I do need to have the libGL.so stuff... without that, I will meet errors when building the source code:

```
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libGLES_CM_translator.so] Error 1
```

Could anyone tell me how to install libGL.so on Ubuntu12.04, 64 bits??

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the bug.

The main problem is that there is no `mesa` file in the `i386-linux-gnu`.

I did two thing, I don't know which one worked, so I just write both of them down.

1) Since I can't install the file for some dependency problem... I just download the deb file(libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal ) and extract the `mesa` file and move that `mesa` file to `libgl1-mesa-dri:386`. The download link [click here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/zh-cn/precise-updates/libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal).

2)I use the command: `Install updates and the package ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 for multiarch support`
I just read the command from this [post](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/2800).

Anyway, it seems that this bug only happens in Ubuntu 12.04.02..  I found post said that he changed back to Ubuntu 12.04.01 and things just worked out...

Well, my bug is fixed. Cheers!